# How to read power and cadence value coming from a cycling trainer?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently using flutter_blue package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) and I want to understand how to listen for services and characteristics like Cycling Power (which is on 0x1818) and Cycling Speed and Cadence (which is on 0x1816) using flutter? I am currently using Kinetic Road Machine Smart Fluid Trainer.